# Drupal - Panels - use variants according to NID

Tags: drupal, drupal-panels

I'm using Panels to overwrite node template (node/%node). I would like the system to use specific variant when a node is loaded. E.g. node 123 should use variant A and node 223 should use variant B. There isn't an option for me to determine that under Selection rules, I'm wondering if I should use PHP Code, and if I do, how should I go about writing the code?

I'm aware of the option of using Panels Node, but by using it, there is no easy way to edit the node thus rendering it a less than desirable choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the easiest thing is probably to throw in some PHP code. It would be prettier to make an extension to the Panels selection rules, but this might be a bit overkill in this case.

Anyways something like

```
return arg(1) == 123;
```

should do it.

Your problem is probably Drupal/Panel cache. I just tested it, and it works fine.

Comment: @googletorp thanks for the quick response.

That was actually the first thing I tried, and it didn't work, thus got me thinking if it wasn't the right method to begin with.

Comment: return arg(1) == 123;  

This new code worked! Thanks heaps for the follow up answer!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do something like this...

```
  $nid = 11;
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == $nid && !arg(2)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
```

Be careful only testing arg(1) as in the previous answer, that will also match users (user/123) as well as any page view that accepts a numeric argument (articles/123).

Comment: Your answer is much complete than googletorp's one. Thanks!